# Como establecer el cursor al principio de un maskedTextBox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un **maskedTextBox** con una mascara del tipo **Int32** y quiero que al dar un click para escribir dentro del control se establezca la posicion del cursor en la primera posicion de izquierda a derecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este control no tiene un metodo setCursorPosition ni nada que identifique como mover el cursor de alguna forma.

Entonces, si quiero moverlo al principio, como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Has probado alguna cosa? Revisate [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para realizar una buena pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: como voy a probar algo si no se como... ahh llevo un año en stackoverflow pero si la pregunta tiene algo mal por favor me la puedes editar o decir que añada algo para arreglarla es q no veo de que otra manera preguntarlo

Comment: @AlexRivas has de investigar usando Google o el buscador de tu elección. La documentacion de C# es más que necesaria. Busca eventos de `focus` y propiedades de los inputs. Has de haber intentado y mostrado en la pregunta dichos intentos para ayudarte sobre los errores que tengas, no sobre la tarea a realizar. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Sabes inglés? [Creo que aquí] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24211466/how-to-position-cursor-at-the-end-of-text-on-a-masked-textbox) está la respuesta que buscas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El control MaskedTextBox no hereda comunmente de un textbox como otros.

Como tiene placeholders embebidos, mover el cursor no es tan simple, porque tiene que cumplir siempre con ciertas reglas.

Sin embargo, hay un metodo en el textbox subyacente que permite mover el cursor al principio.

El metodo [Select](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.select?view=netframework-4.7.2), permite seleccionar una posición y marcar un texto.

Entonces, podemos hacer un poco de trampa, y en el metodo click del MTB, hacer lo siguiente:

```
private void maskedTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    maskedTextBox1.Select(0, 0);     
}
```

Comment: si fue lo mismo que lei gracias es lo que estaba buscando